# Directed graph in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find out which edges from a graph are bidirectional. Each row is an edge. For each starting node A, I am searching each corresponding end node B if they have node A as an ending point:

```
for ending_point_B in nodeA:
    nodeA in ending_points_of_B
```

Disregard for now repeated entries in df['S']. How can I optimize this search? I suspect something along the lines of groupby. This way takes too much time for my real graph.

Thank you

```
from pandas import *

def missing_node(node):
    set1 = set(df[df.E == node].S.values)
    set2 = set(df.E[df.S == node].values)
    return list(set1.difference(set2))

x = [1,1,2,2,3]
y = [2,3,1,3,1]

df = DataFrame([x,y]).T
df.columns = ['S','E'] #Start & End

df['Missing'] = df.S.apply(missing_node)

df:

   S  E Missing
0  1  2      []
1  1  3      []
2  2  1      []
3  2  3      []
4  3  1     [2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is great, but not sure you need it here.  Something like the following should give you the links that aren't bidirectional:

```
x = [1,1,2,2,3]
y = [2,3,1,3,1]

fwd = set( zip(x,y) )
rev = set( zip(y,x) )
print ' not bi: ', fwd.difference(rev)
```

This returns:

> > > not bi:  set([(2, 3)])

Comment: Yes, I didn't need pandas but for a posterior analysis it became useful and was just trying to understand pandas' data structures better. Thanks for the zip tip.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to find all node pairs that are not bidirectional. In the example above, the only such pair of nodes is 2 and 3. Given this, you could do the following:

```
In [1]: df['is_bi'] = df.index.map(lambda x: np.any(map(lambda y: np.all(y), df.ix[x][['E', 'S']].values == df.values)))
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   S  E  is_bi
0  1  2   True
1  1  3   True
2  2  1   True
3  2  3  False
4  3  1   True
```

So `df[-df.is_bi]` will give you all pairs of nodes that are not bidirectional:

```
In [3]: df[-df.is_bi][['S', 'E']]
Out[3]: 
   S  E
3  2  3
```

I have the feeling that I overly complicated this and there must be a way to do this with pandas-native functions, but the above solution does the trick.